# Java ShutdownHook with server

Tags: java, server, shutdown-hook

I'm writing a basic server in java. I have a Server class that waits for requests:

```
class Server{
    public void listen(){
        ServerSocket listenSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        while(true){
            Socket clientSocket = listenSocket.accept();
            // start new thread for the connection
            new Connection(clientSocket, this).start();
        }
    }

    public void save(){
        //save stuff
    }
}
```

I added a ShutdownHook to the program so it can save it's data on shutdown. My main looks like this:

```
Server server = new Server();
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        server.save();
    }
}));
server.listen();
```

But the ShutdownHook fires only if I delete server.listen(); (when it's not in while(true)). Is there a way to save the server's data on exit?

Comment: Make thread that is calling `listen()` a deamon thread.

Comment: The thread that is calling listen() is the main thread. It throws IllegalThreadStateException if I make it a deamon thread.

Comment: Make a deamon thread and call from there.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. I figured out why: I guess IntelliJ kills the process aggressively and won't let the shutdown hook to be run. If I run the server in cmd and close it with ctrl+c (on windows) the hook will run.

Comment: You didnt say you run it from ide xD xD

Comment: Didn't think it was relevant :D